# Multiple lines of the same plot with amXYChart() function

Tags: r, amcharts

I'm trying to use the amXYChart() function for the first time and I would like to represent two lines on the same plot but I don't manage to.

For example with that dataset. I can represent one line with the code below.

```
x <- data.frame("value" = 1:5, "cats" = c(10,20,30,40,50), "dogs" = c(15,25,35,36,48))
amXYChart(x="value", y="dogs", dataProvider=x, keepNA = TRUE) %>%
  addGraph(xField = "value", yField = "dogs")
```

However when I try to represent the two lines, my plot window is empty (Only the x axis is displayed).

```
x <- data.frame("value" = 1:5, "cats" = c(10,20,30,40,50), "dogs" = c(15,25,35,36,48))
amXYChart(x="value", y=c("cats","dogs"), dataProvider=x, keepNA = TRUE) %>%
  addGraph(xField = "value", yField = c("cats","dogs"))
```

Also I'm trying to use this package because of interactivity but when I place my curser of the plot (the first one) nothing appears. With the example below it works perfectly.

```
library(lubridate)
data("data_stock_2")
amTimeSeries(data_stock_2, 'date', c('ts1', 'ts2'))
```

Is interactivity only for time series data ?

Thanks very much for helping !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use `amSerialChart` as follows:

```
amSerialChart(dataProvider=dts, keepNA = TRUE, categoryField="value") %>%
  addGraph(valueField = "cats") %>%
  addGraph(valueField = "dogs") %>%
  setChartCursor()
```

or

```
vars <- c("cats", "dogs")
p <- amSerialChart(dataProvider=dts, keepNA = TRUE, categoryField="value") 
for (vark in vars) {
  p <- p %>% addGraph(valueField = vark)
}
p %>% setChartCursor()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks ! This is what I was looking for. Just one more question: is there a way to to this without adding addGraph() each time ? 
I didn't find a group option like I usually use with ggplot2. For example it could be something like this :

x <- data.frame("value" = rep(1:5,2), type=c(rep("cats",each=5),rep("dogs",each=5)), y = c(10,20,30,40,50,15,25,35,36,48))
p <- ggplot(x, aes(x=value, y=y, group=factor(type))) + geom_line(aes(color=factor(type)))


Thank you.

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I needed. Thank you very much !